# Copy local dictionary into global dictionary

Tags: json, swift, xcode, dictionary, google-directions-api

I am having a problem where I create a dictionary in a method and then try to make a field equal to the dictionary!

So:

```
var theJson : NSDictionary!

func someMethod()
{
   if let theDictionary = valueFromGoogleDirections as? NSDictionary
   theJson = theDictionary
}

func fieldTest()
{
   print(theJson)
}
```

after calling someMethod and then fieldTest the fieldTest method always prints "{ }" which I figure means it is an empty dictionary. What is going on? I know that theDictionary is getting values because I am able to use its values from within the someMethod method.

Comment: Is `someMethod` making any async call?, if it is then you need to use completion block.

Comment: I do not believe it is but I will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

theJson = theDictionary.copy()